# Dependency on JAR that depends on a SO file

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin

I'm developing an application (WebRTC) which has dependency on a JAR file that has dependency on a SO file.

I am able to load the JAR file but my issue is that it fails to load the SO file.

> dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.webrtc.peerrtc-2/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so") failed: dlopen failed: "/data/app-lib/com.webrtc.peerrtc-2/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so" has unexpected e_machine: 3

Answer (score 3):

> "/data/app-lib/com.webrtc.peerrtc-2/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so" has unexpected e_machine: 3

This means that the dynamic linker has found a library built for e_machine 3, which is i386, when it expected something else such as one built for an ARM architecture.

Normally Android decides which library from an APK to extract for use from the name of the folder containing it.  It would seem that either your jar, or your project itself, is putting an i386 version of the library in the place where the one for whatever target architecture you are running on should go.

You might try using zip file tools to examine both the jar and the apk.

If you are developing on a Linux system, the `file` command may be able to tell you the machine type specified *within* a .so file, allowing you to determine if it is has been placed in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting the so library in the appropriate src/main/jniLibs folder for the given architecture? (If you are still in Eclipse, it has to go under libs/[arch]). After putting it there, Android should load it and the JAR should find it.

Comment: I tried in both Eclipse and Android studio by putting .so file in libs->armeabi-v7a(eclipse), jniLibs->armeabi-v7a(AndroidStudio) still the error is same ...

Comment: One more error if i run in the version 4.1  
Fatal error: Cannot load library: get_lib_extents[742]:.so is not a valid ELF object

Comment: @user1242359 Putting a non-arm library in the arm folder won't help - what this is saying is that the folders must contain libraries of the matching ABI.  So if the device has one of the arm ABI's then you must find an arm version of the library to put in that folder, not the x86 one which triggered this error message.